# How to avoid from a bulky tranformer in the flyback topology?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I want to know how to make a flyback transformer with these parameters:

Core EI-30, 46Turns of 3strands of AWG27.

Regarding the "[Switching Power Supplies A - Z](https://books.google.com/books?id=cuyyQ3N_8hIC&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=13.5mm%20to%20530mils&source=bl&ots=sCpDC_REXe&sig=ACfU3U2xpzWfML9ivSYwICUJ7vKTz9rpMw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQnKCNycP3AhXGu6QKHXhKBIoQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=13.5mm%20to%20530mils&f=false)" book, I didn't understand how the writer tried to wind the transformer.

> The problem is that a bunch of 46 twisted strands (of AWG 27) is
> going to be bulky, difﬁ cult to wind, and will also increase the leakage inductance. So we
> may like to use, say, 11 or 12 strands of AWG 27 twisted together into one bunch, and
> then take four of these bunches (all electrically in parallel), laid out side by side to form
> one layer of the transformer. For a two-turns secondary, therefore, we would wind two
> layers of this.

I will be grateful if you could kindly let me know about the above procedure.

Answer (score 2):

1. Initial design step: Take 46 strands (pieces) of 27 AWG.  Twist together to make a rope/cable.  Make two loops of this on the bobbin.
2. Initial design is inferior for multiple reasons.  Change configuration.  Take 11-12 strands of 27 AWG.  Twist together to make a rope/cable.  Using four such cables in parallel (laid flat together), make two loops around the bobbin.

Visual aid: 46 strands in one cable vs. 12 strands in 4.

[image: litz cross sections]

The passage in the book begins with suggesting foil, a very wide format indeed, which will give even lower leakage inductance.  The downside is it's harder to handle, and maybe the wires are better for that reason.  Using a flatter layup (multiple wires laid flat side-by-side) gets something of a hybrid between the two cases.

I will add a note, this example is somewhat erroneous: the proceeding page seems to say skin depth is all that needs to be considered, ignoring proximity effect.  In fact, the skin effect from each wire in a bundle, affects each neighboring wire in turn, greatly magnifying the effect.  I would guess 36 AWG would be more suitable (with many more strands per cable), at least as far as minimizing AC resistance.  (A practical, commercial design might compromise, using wire somewhere inbetween: not needing minimal AC resistance, but still less than 27 AWG would give.)

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Is there any good reference that I can deepen my understanding of wire winding? Some questions arise based on your explanations.